# OpenCV with raspberry pi cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV) not showing correct colors

Tags: python, opencv

Going through the tutorials and trying to figure this out. When I run:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

cap = cv.VideoCapture(-1)
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        print("no frame")
    img = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv.imshow('frame', img)
```

I get a nice gray image as I would expect. But if I change that second to last line to

```
img = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
```

Then I get this thing with the colors all screwed up:

[image: example picture of bad colors]

I get something a lot closer if I use COLOR_BGR2RGB but it's still not right. I'm usually not so blue:
[image: another example picture with less bad colors]

I'm assuming what it's doing is reading in the image as BGR, and then applying some sort of transform on it so that it's in a different format, but when I display or save the image, it still thinks its BGR so now the image isn't displayed correctly? That would at least explain why I'm so blue. The red and blue channels just got swapped. I tried COLOR_BGR2BGR but apparently that's not a thing.

Comment: What kind of image (appearance) do you expect `cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV` should give when displayed? Even after converting to HSV color space, you still have some three channel 8-bit unsigned integer image, which `cv2.imshow` treats as a regular BGR image for displaying. What you see is the Hue channel mapped to blue, Saturation mapped to green, and Value mapped to red. So, what do you actually want to see?

Comment: I'd like to see a regular image. Basically how do I read in the data without mapping it to a different space?

Comment: Simply remove the `cvtColor(...)` call!?

Comment: See, now that makes sense. I knew I was missing something.

Comment: @HansHirse Do you want to write that as an answer, and I'll accept it?